# Android Studio Ctrl B shortcut, using Mouse Center Scrolling Wheel

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

On Android Studio 4.0 I was able to to navigate to in the place of (Ctrl+B) go to Declaration,

How can I assign Center Will for the ShortCut( Ctrl +B ) so I can use the center wheel instead of keyboard, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio, Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap

You can search for declaration. You will find shortcut available mapped to Ctrl+B. If mouse shortcut is not added, right click and add a mouse shortcut. Hope it works.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the wheel button is not supported. Everything else should be working properly. 